# Word 2010 VBA - Nested Do Until ... Loop for Search and Replaces

Tags: vba, search, replace, ms-word

I'm attempting to create a nested Do Until... Loop that will perform 15 different search and replaces in Word documents.  I need to accomplish the following (semicolon at end only for listing purposes):

```
Search  space ^t; replace with ^t;
Search ^t space; replace with ^t;
search ^t^t; replace with ^t;
search ^t^p; replace with ^p;
search $^t; replace with $;
search $ space; replace with $;
search ^t%; replace with %;
search space %; replace with %;
search (^t; replace with (;
search ( space; replace with (;
search ^t); replace with );
search space ); replace with );
search space ^p; replace with ^p;
search ^p space; replace with ^p; and
search ^p^p; replace with ^p.
```

I've recorded the macro and would like to edit it, replacing the numerous 
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
that occurred for each search/replace in the macro until the result was 0 instances.  I know a Do Until... Loop will make this macro more efficient.  Please help!

Comment: So you want to loop through all the Word Documents and do the find and replace? Are the Documents all open? Or stored in a folder?

Comment: I'd be using the macro on one Word document at a time - downloaded from a website and need to be converted and cleaned up in Word 2010. These documents can be hundreds of pages (including financial tables hence all the extra tabs after its converted) and these search/replaces are part of extensive reformatting.  So, I need to loop through one document and catch all instances of each search/replace item. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should at least get you started:

```
Dim searches() As String
Dim replaces() As String

searches = Split("( , %", ",")
replaces = Split("(,%", ",")

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(searches) To UBound(searches)
    With Selection.Find
        Do
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = searches(i)
            .Replacement.Text = replaces(i)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Loop While .Found
    End With
Next i
```

The search strings and replacement strings are comma delimited and have to be the same number of elements - only two were included for clarity (it'll be ugly with the vbTab and vbCr concatenated in all over the place).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm going to test it.  To add the other search and replacement strings, can I place all 15 in the = Split lines enclosed in quotes and comma delimited?

Comment: @Luuti - Yes.  I kept it short so it's a bit more clear than something like: `searches = Split(" " & vbTab & ",  ," & " " & vbCr & ", %", ",")`